# Htaccess Redirection for url with matching string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Need help on 301 redirection for all string matches 'start' parameter in oldtoys

**Incorrect URL been generated**

```
http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_oldtoys&view=category&Itemid=2&start=45&limitstart=300
http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_oldtoys&view=category&Itemid=2&start=30&limitstart=275
http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_oldtoys&view=category&Itemid=2&start=15&limitstart=250
```

**Correct URL**

```
http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_oldtoys&view=category&Itemid=2&limitstart=300
http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_oldtoys&view=category&Itemid=2&limitstart=275
http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_oldtoys&view=category&Itemid=2&limitstart=250
```

This only pertains to old toys component
Can someone help on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(option=com_oldtoys&.*)&start=[0-9]+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hello Jon, Its not working, coming output is:-      http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_oldtoys&view=category&Itemid=2&limit

Comment: Yep, yours too works now. Any comment on Anubhava code - as that too works too, or both are equally good !!! Thanks for your time

Comment: @RuchikaModi anubhava's regex is more strict, with the only variance being the `Itemid`'s value and the `limitstart`'s value. There can't be any other parameters, which is good if it's what you want. The regex that I used only needs to start with `option=com_oldtoys&` and the `start` parameter can be anywhere along with any other parameters in the query string. Depends on how strict you want the match to be

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(option=com_oldtoys&view=category&Itemid=[^&]*)&start=[^&]*&(limitstart=[^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ $0?%1&%2 [L,NC,R=301]
```